# Exponential Decay Help

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

Hi I don't mean to sound like a clueless student who should already know this subject but I am really stumped on the topic of exponential growth and decay. Namely this one question:

"When zombies finally take over, the population of the Earth will decrease exponentially. Every HOUR that goes by the human population will decrease by 5%. The population today is 6,000,000,000, find a function P that gives the population of the earth d DAYS after the beginning of the zombie takeover."

This really puts me in between a rock and a hard place. As you can imagine I researched this question and various methods of exponential growth everywhere online, in my textbook, and in my class notes, but I still come full circle and find myself back to square one, with no clue what so ever on how this works. I would really appreciate it if someone could at least point me in the right direction like how to model a decay with exponential variables involving HOURS and DAYS as the question says. I already know my initial formula being 6,000,000,000(0.85) I just need to know the exponents used! Is it 6,000,000,000(0.85)^d/60, 6,000,000,000(0.85)^d/1? Or something like that? Please help I really want to grasp this concept!

Comment: You need to precise formulate the knowledge you have about the system and rewrite this formulation to the target formulation. There is nothing to search online.

Comment: Let's say that you have the evolution of population defined by recurrence relation: each day is the population by 5% smaller than the previous day and you have the initial condition that some day there is 6 billion people. You may start writing the population in the initial day, second day after the initial day, third day and so.  With this written, you may guess the formula for the nth day. You need to check, that your guess was correct. And if so, this is your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are doing calculus, we will use the real mathematician's exponential function $e^x$. Measure time in hours, with $t=0$ when the *exponential decay* began. Then
$$P(t)=P(0)e^{-kt},\tag{1}$$
where $k$ is a constant. The initial population $P(0)$ is $6\times 10^9$.

First we find $k$. We are told that $P(1)=(0.95)P(0)$. Substituting in $(1),$ we obtain
$$(0.95)P(0)=P(0)e^{-k}.$$
Do some cancellation, and take the natural logarithm of both sides. We obtain $k=-\ln(0.95)$.

Now Equation $(1)$ can be rewritten as
$$P(t)=P(0)e^{-(-t\ln(0.95))}=e^{t\ln(0.95)}=P(0)(0.95)^t.\tag{2}$$

Note that we could have obtained the form $P(t)=P(0)(0.95)^t$ far faster. For every hour that goes by, the population gets multiplied by $0.95$.

When $d$ days have elapsed, $24d$ hours have elapsed. Set $t=24d$ in either version of $(2).$

Answer (score 1):

The number of hours in $d$ days is $24d$, so the population multiplies by $0.95$ that many times.  Hence
$$
P(d) = 6\cdot10^9\cdot 0.95^{24d}
$$
where $d$ is the number of days.

You don't need $e$ until you talk about instantaneous rates of change, i.e. derivatives.  Then you have
$$
0.95 = e^{\ln0.95}
$$
so
$$
P(d) = 6\cdot10^9\cdot e^{24(\ln0.95)d}.
$$